# What is the connotation for gay蜜 and 闺蜜?

Tags: culture, meaning

What is the connotation for gay蜜? Is the connotation literally that the two guys that it refers to are gay, or is it like the english 'man-date' where it is just two close friends going to do something together.

Same question for 闺蜜.

Is this usually used for young adults (18-30 years old)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage is varied and depends on the scenarios so there's no strict definition.
But generally,

gay蜜 originally means a close gay friend of a girl, now it's applied to the non-gay group. Again it's not safe to say "A is a gay蜜 of B" unless you are close to A or B. Sometimes it's rude but it's ok to use this word safely within your friend circle.

闺蜜 mean a close female friend of a girl. This word could track back a long time ago. gay蜜 and 男闺蜜 are originated from this word.

闺蜜 are used at all ages. gay蜜 are used by adult(born after 1980s)

Answer (score 4):

gay蜜 is not a formal word, usually used on Internet or in oral languages by the young.

When a girl has a gay male close friend, she will call him "gay蜜".

e.g. "他是我的gay蜜。" means he's my close friend and he's gay.

Is "gay蜜""闺蜜" usually used for young adults (18-30 years old)? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the meaning of gay for 蜜? I have never heard that!

蜜 is honey, but you wouldn't call your gf 蜜 like we might in English. That would be 亲爱的， 宝宝。

闺蜜 is a woman's best friend, not a lesbian.

男闺蜜 could maybe refer to an unmanly man, possibly gay.

基佬 is slang for a gay guy.

Two men who are friends might refer to each other with 兄弟 or 铁哥们。